# Aliasing in objects

Tags: java, output, pointer-aliasing

When running the function foo1, why does the output for this code will be: 15 **30** 5
and not 15 **15** 5 ?

I underdtand that the pointer of the object v is now points to the object va1, so the output for the code line: System.out.print(v.getI() + " ");
should be 15. So why is it 30 ?

```
public class Value
{
    private int _i;

    public Value()
    {
        _i=15;
    }

    public int getI()
    {
        return _i;
    }

    public void setI (int i)
    {
        _i=i;
    }

}

public class TestValue
{
    public static void foo1()
    {
        int i=5;
        Value v= new Value();
        v.setI(10);
        foo2(v,i);
        System.out.print(v.getI() + " ");
        System.out.print(i+ " ");

    }

    public static void foo2( Value v, int i)
    {
        v.setI(30);
        i=10;
        Value va1= new Value();
        v=va1;
        System.out.print (v.getI() + " ");
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Java only supports **pass-by-value**. So when you pass an object "v" to the method **foo2** a copy of the reference "v" is created. So when you set **v = val1** in **foo2** the copy of the reference is being changed in **foo2** not the original reference "v" in **foo1**.

Comment: Java's "references" being values is really, really confusing nomenclature. It's more intuitive to think of them as "handles".

Comment: Thanks @DonRoby

millimoose, yes it is quite confusing initially.